# Replace _strdup by _strdup

Tags: strdup

I got the following compiling error on VS2013:

```
error C4996: '_strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for details.
```

So it asks me to replace "_strdup" by the same thing.

I have seen many error asking to replace _strdup (POSIX) by strdup but not that.

Also the same code works on many other people machine (with same project properties normally). So I don't think I need to change the code but something on my PC.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (not on purpose) modified a Microsoft file. That is why i got this weird error

Comment: File a bug report with Microsoft? Can't delete this comment on mobile, ignore me

Comment: No, I meant that because I modified a Microsoft file I should not have modified I got that error.